# How t transfer money paypal to payment?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am new in paypal API. I am trying to transfer money from one paypal account to another paypal account but I am getting error. so please check my code and tell me what is wrong error.Your suggestions are welcome.

This is the **code** I am trying :

```
$receiverList=array();
$receiverList["receiver"][$counter]["amount"]=50;
$receiverList["receiver"][$counter]["email"]='amandeep.singh@#######.com';
$receiverList["receiver"][$counter]["paymentType"]="PAY";
$receiverList["receiver"][$counter]["invoiceId"]=1548569;

$payLoad["actionType"]="PAY";
$payLoad["cancelUrl"]="";
$payLoad["currencyCode"]="EUR";
$payLoad["receiverList"]=$receiverList;
$payLoad["feesPayer"]="SENDER ";
$payLoad["sender"]["email"]='amandeep.singh@#######.com';

//run the call
$API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay";


$payLoad["requestEnvelope"]= array("errorLanguage"=>urlencode("en_US"),"detailLevel"=>urlencode("ReturnAll"));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array(
'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON',
'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON',
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: amandeep.singh-facilitator_api1.mobilyte.com',
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: AZVMY9FZK2J#####',
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AodeBybN3aK381NetHgWkUW1####',
'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W28##########3'));  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payLoad));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($response, 1);
```

after call above curl, paypal return this **error**:-

```
Array ( [responseEnvelope] => Array ( [timestamp] => 2016-02-21T21:58:24.854-08:00 [ack] => Failure [correlationId] => 3693e36af347f [build] => 20367699 ) [error] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [errorId] => 560022 [domain] => PLATFORM [subdomain] => Application [severity] => Error [category] => Application [message] => The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value [parameter] => Array ( [0] => X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **APPID** for the sand-box and live are different to one another.

The Sand box should be used with the following ID :

> APP-80W284485P519543T

And the live is used with the ID which is similar to that of APP credentials.

Comment: Yes. After changing app iid, my error is resolved. Please update me, can i transfer money from one account to another paypal account and vise versa

Comment: I am getting this error now:  Account amandeep.singh@xxx.com is restricted

Comment: I could solve the problem by removing the "feesPayer" param, which needs to be the default value (i.e., EACHRECEIVER) in case of a unilateral payment.

Comment: after using "$payLoad["feesPayer"]="EACHRECEIVER";" getting same error

Comment: Issue is resolved. Their was issue related to Email id: i was using sandbox id. but i change email is to pankaj.kumar-buyer@360itpro.com as per sandbox

Comment: now i am getting this responce:-  Array
(
    [responseEnvelope] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 2016-02-21T23:10:45.665-08:00
            [ack] => Success
            [correlationId] => ece5e381125bb
            [build] => 20367699
        )

    [payKey] => AP-7RF89755578111227
    [paymentExecStatus] => CREATED
). can i see how much money is transfer to any user

Comment: cool...Please accept if my suggestion helped you..This will help others in future

Comment: but need you more help. Getting You don't have any transactions in sand dashboard .

Comment: please update me on :- "Getting You don't have any transactions in sand dashboard . "

Comment: Read this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sandbox-testing/configuring-accounts/